# Remove undesired lines in 3D figures

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view/v=25,view/h=110,xlabel=$a_1$,ylabel=$a_2$,zlabel=$a_3$,
            colormap={darkblue}{color(1)=(blue!80!black!90) color(2)=(blue!80!black!70) color(3)=(blue!80!black!50) color(4)=(blue!80!black!30)},
            xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=1, grid=major]
        \addplot3[%xmin=0,xmax=1,
            opacity=0, 
            fill opacity=1,
            table/row sep=\\,
            patch,
            patch type=polygon,
            vertex count=3,
            patch table with point meta={%
            % pt1 pt2 pt3 cdata
              7 3   5   2.82843 \\
              2 3   6   2.12132 \\
              3 7   6   2.12132 \\
              3 1   5   2.82843 \\
              2 0   3   1. \\
              0 1   3   1. \\
              1 0   5   2. \\
              4 0   6   3. \\
              0 2   6   3. \\
              0 4   5   2. \\
              4 6   5   1. \\
              6 7   5   1. \\
              }
        ]
        table {
            x y z \\
            0   0   0 \\
            0   0   0.873387 \\
            0   0.873387    0 \\
            0   0.873387    0.873387 \\
            0.623336    0   0 \\
            0.623336    0   0.250051 \\
            0.623336    0.250051    0 \\
            0.623336    0.250051    0.250051 \\
        };
\end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

plots the following 3D figure:

[image]

which shows division lines in polygon faces right and up, and also in the front face of the figure.

Is there any way to remove these lines?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I must admit that I do not understand why but `faceted color=none` seems to do the trick. I would have expected that I need to set this color to the one of the `fill`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view/v=25,view/h=110,xlabel=$a_1$,ylabel=$a_2$,zlabel=$a_3$,
            colormap={darkblue}{color(1)=(blue!80!black!90) color(2)=(blue!80!black!70) color(3)=(blue!80!black!50) color(4)=(blue!80!black!30)},
            xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,zmin=0,zmax=1, grid=major]
        \addplot3[%xmin=0,xmax=1,
            faceted color=none,
            line width=0pt,
            fill opacity=1,
            table/row sep=\\,
            patch,
            patch type=polygon,
            vertex count=3,
            patch table with point meta={%
            % pt1 pt2 pt3 cdata
              7 3   5   2.82843 \\
              2 3   6   2.12132 \\
              3 7   6   2.12132 \\
              3 1   5   2.82843 \\
              2 0   3   1. \\
              0 1   3   1. \\
              1 0   5   2. \\
              4 0   6   3. \\
              0 2   6   3. \\
              0 4   5   2. \\
              4 6   5   1. \\
              6 7   5   1. \\
              }
        ]
        table {
            x y z \\
            0   0   0 \\
            0   0   0.873387 \\
            0   0.873387    0 \\
            0   0.873387    0.873387 \\
            0.623336    0   0 \\
            0.623336    0   0.250051 \\
            0.623336    0.250051    0 \\
            0.623336    0.250051    0.250051 \\
        };
\end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user1993416 Thanks! On p. 141 of the pgfplots it actually says that this is the right way to do it.

Comment: I have tried `faceted color=none,` in my plots but does not work. It leaves the figure with the lines. I do not know why. I have TeX live 2018 I think it is updated.

Comment: I have noticed I must remove opacity = 0 and also add line width=0pt, and then it works. Thanks.

Comment: @user1993416 As for removing `opacity=0`, I agree, that's what I did in my answer, and as for `linewidth=0pt`, that's optional, I think, it is probably less confusing to leave it out.